# Unable to start managed server in running mode ,it has been stucked after <BEA-170027>

Tags: weblogic

Unable to start managed wls_report server in 12c ,it was strucked after this  the server has successfully established connection with domain level diagnostic services.

It has been stucked managed server .

I have 2 managed server ,one is running wls_forms and wls_reports stuck .

Please help me . it's very urgent

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.